# How can a constant margin/padding be created between two sections responsively?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two sections stacked. I'm using a `position:relative` on the container `div` and then using `position:absolute` on the child `div`s to position them with respect to the top of the parent container.

This is my code (also on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7geLh0kf/)):

```css
html,body{height: 100%; width: 100%;}

h1{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Avenir', sans-serif;
  color: #212121;
} 

h2{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Avenir', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #424242;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Avenir', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#header{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  max-width: 960px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#header h1{padding-top: 5px;}
#header {max-width: 800px;}

#projects{
  position: absolute;
  top: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <section id = "header">
    <h1>Name Lastname</h1>
    <h2>Description, Description</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam euismod non metus id semper. Integer volutpat, mauris vitae pulvinar rhoncus, lacus lectus euismod augue, sit amet interdum lectus leo et magna. Curabitur in tellus vel tellus finibus faucibus quis sit amet risus. Etiam id sagittis ligula. Ut facilisis, nisi eu.!
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id = "projects">
    <p>Another paragraph on projects</p>
  </section>

</div>
```

I am trying to make the page responsive but, when I reduce the width of the page, the header `div` (top section) crunches into the bottom projects div which makes it illegible.

How can I create a constant spacing between the two divs?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for the guide! Just read it!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the above comment, the answer is to remove the `position: absolute;`. The default flow within the parent container will be for the child divs to stack. You can then adjust the spacing between the child divs with `margin-top` or `margin-bottom`.